# Have Android EditText appear to be in focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

Would it be possible to have an edit text appear to be in focus but not not actually be in focus. I would like the bright blue underline on two or more of the edit texts in my UI but never have them in focus or have the blinking insertion point. I have tried `android:focusable="false"` but that makes it grayed out. I'v also tried out a number of other combination but can't seem to find one that works.

Comment: It seems that having multiple EditTexts in focus isn't an option. I guess that the only other option would be to create a style that changes the appearance of the out of focus view and apply it to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
setSelected(true);
```

I think it will help

**Edit:**
To summarize I think you cannot really setSelection on multiple edittext at the same time but you can customize your editext by giving them custom background using selectors so they will look like selected.

You can accomplish it by using these tools that allow quick resources generators.
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: Same thing, only one can be in focus.

Comment: You want all of them to be focused?

Comment: I don't need them to be in focus for the purpose of being in focus..just the color that it gets from being in focus.

Comment: Why don't you use custom resources? By doing that you can fully customize your edittexts

Comment: This could be really useful, check it out  http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ :D

Comment: For some things I am not too familiar with doing. Things like image buttons I can do, but I tried changing the background of the EditText and it just flattens out the look of it.

Comment: If you use the assets studio link and you select "Android Holo Color Generator" they will provide you all the resources ready to be used.

Comment: I guess you could summarize this conversation saying that you can't focus on multiple elements but can make it appear to with blah blah so I could accept something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<EditText ... >
 <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Applying it to the two EditText's will just make the last one in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically you can "request focus" to your view:

```
myEditText.requestFocus();
```

or via xml:

```
<EditText>
 <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```